# PHPStorm Squawks on @return void for __construct()

Tags: php, constructor, return, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using PHPStorm and trying to figure out how to make it stop squawking when a `__construct()` has `@return void` in its PHPDocs...

According the PHPDocs, `void` is valid, or the `@return` may be omitted. That being said, is there a way to fix this or is it a bug?

Comment: As you have said: *"@return may be omitted"*. `@return` does not really make sense for `__construct`, so just do not use it there.

Comment: It's used in a lot of frameworks and other scripts, regardless of what I may or may not do. IDEs should be set up to follow standards, not their own interpretation of things. If it's optional, it should be optional and not enforced or at least have an option to choose rather or not to be strict about it. Regardless, the question was not about rather to use it or not, the question was if there was such an option to disable the warning.

Comment: All options for PHPDoc inspections scan be found in `Settings | Inspections | PHP | PHPDoc` -- unfortunately I do not see anything there that would allow to ignore such warning.

Comment: Related links from [JetBrains YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18678) and [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/702).

Comment: According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) the `__construct()` method does return `void` so this is a false flag. I don't know a way to suppress it other than omitting it.

Comment: Very late comment. Not that `@return void` for constructors is also wrong since you cannot declare the return type anyway: https://3v4l.org/iPik1
I'd say the PHP documentation is incorrect by trying to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not turn off just this one very specific inspection. The whole PHPDoc method signature inspection would need to be turned off.  Fortunately you can [set the scope of the inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-inspection.html#scopes) to be only your own project code, ignoring 3rd party libraries and frameworks.  See the scopes dropdown on the right under the description.

[image: PHPStorm Inspections Screenshot]

Also on a case-by-case basis you can turn off the inspection above each PHPDoc comment:

```
/** @noinspection PhpDocSignatureInspection */
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() ...
```

Answer (score -1):

See [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html) for how to suppress the warning for a statement. You can hover the portion of code and select the option from the drop-down. You will have to do this for each affected constructor though.

I don't see an Inspection Tool option to suppress this warning in a way that won't expose other issues.

Comment: Scratch that, it is difficult to bring up. However, this will disable the entire inspection.